# Calling summaryCoding() in RQDA raises an error

Tags: r, rqda

I'm attempting to use the RQDA package. I've tried to use the `summaryCoding()` (or `SummaryCoding()` or `summarycoding()` ) command with no success. `getCodingTable()` works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the "s" at the end of the word codings, it should be:

```
summaryCodings()
```

(respect the capitals letters too, R is case sensitive). To avoid this kind of issues you may use Rstudio, which provides code completion. I've made tutorials on YouTube in French, you can [find them here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL52377017A7137925&feature=plcp). To install R Studio watch video 2 3 or 4 (windows linux or mac). To see how to use the command prompt watch video 20. It's all in French but by watching the videos you can understand it even if you don't speak french.

Comment: Yes - it's wrong in the manual. From the package maintainer: "There is a typo in the manual, it should be summaryCodings()."

Yes, I had thought about watching your videos, but I wasn't sure where to begin. I'll definitely try Rstudio. I'd be grateful for any other suggestions (videos, links, etc) e.g. what I may want to look at after coding qualitative data or useful graphics, charts, etc... 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

well after coding you can put your code into category code. Sometimes the same code goes to many category codes. Then you can create a graph (cf. video 18). You have also the crossCodes()... But usually it's quite difficult to put a lot of numbers in a qualitative study. Personally speaking i retrieve the codes per "code category" and I do not hesitate to cite a lot of codes in my written analysis document. And if my files are interviews, I usually link the opinion of the speakers with other studies from a science article, for instance...

Comment: By the way the RQDAtuto channel on YouTube provides videos in English now. Thanks.